# Custom User Control Does not Auto Size

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a chat application using C# and have hit a snag on how to create chat bubble that is outgoing and incoming message. My problem is how to auto resize the chat bubble based on the text on the custom Usercontrol. Here I have created a Created a custom UserControl and have added a label and set autosize to false for both Usercontrol and the label. usercontrol background is transparent and the label docked to the right. My main problem is the bubble size does not automatically size according to the text content passed. The height of the bubble remain constants. Here is my Sender Bubble and how am adding it to Panel in another form.

```
public partial class SenderBubble : UserControl
    {
        public SenderBubble()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            label1.AutoSize = false; // Set AutoSize to false
            this.AutoSize = false;



        }
        private void ChangeLabelSize()
        {
          
            SizeF size = label1.CreateGraphics().MeasureString(label1.Text, label1.Font);
            label1.MaximumSize = new Size(this.Width, 0);

            label1.Width = this.Width;
            this.MinimumSize = new Size(0, 0);
            this.Height = (int)size.Height;
            this.AutoSize = false;
            Console.WriteLine("Height:" + size.Height);//height of text is not changing*/
            /**
             log output
             Height:20
             Height:20
             */
        }

        public int LabelHeight
        {
            get
            {
                return this.Height = label1.Height;
            }
        }

        [Editor("System.ComponentModel.Design.MultilineStringEditor, System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", typeof(UITypeEditor))]
        public string Body
        {
            get
            {
                return label1.Text;
            }
            set
            {
                label1.Text = value;
                ChangeLabelSize();
            }
        }


     
       //to add border radius
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {

           GraphicsPath path = RoundedRectangle.Create(label1.ClientRectangle, 8, RoundedRectangle.RectangleCorners.All);
            label1.Region = new Region(path);

            base.OnPaint(e);
        }

      



    }
    
    //this is how am calling / adding the sender bubble.
    int basey=bublePanel.Location.Y;
       private void HandleUserChats(String message)
        {

            SenderBubble bubble = new SenderBubble();     
            bubble.Time = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm");
            bubble.TimeColor = Color.Black;
            bubble.Body = message;
            bubble.Top = basey;
            bublePanel.Controls.Add(bubble);//bublePanel is A Panel which have set autoscroll=true
            int width = bublePanel.ClientSize.Width - bubble.Width;
           
            bubble.Left = width;
            basey += bubble.LabelHeight;

            bublePanel.ScrollControlIntoView(bubble);
            txt_msg_box.Clear();
            txt_msg_box.Focus();





        }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    public partial class SenderBubble : UserControl
{
    public SenderBubble()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label1.AutoSize = false; 
        this.AutoSize = false;
        label1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill; 
    }

    public int LabelHeight
    {
        get
        {
            return label1.Height;
        }
    }

    [Editor("System.ComponentModel.Design.MultilineStringEditor, System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    public string Body
    {
        get
        {
            return label1.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            label1.Text = value;
            ChangeLabelSize();
        }
    }

    private void ChangeLabelSize()
    {
        
        label1.AutoSize = true;
        label1.MaximumSize = new Size(this.Width, 0);
        this.MinimumSize = new Size(0, 0);
        label1.AutoSize = false;

       
        this.Width = label1.Width;
        this.Height = label1.Height;
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        GraphicsPath path = RoundedRectangle.Create(ClientRectangle, 8, RoundedRectangle.RectangleCorners.All);
        Region = new Region(path);
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Will my code to change the bubble panel change? I have tried your code but the height does not change still.